# What is the difference between an Abstract Data Type(ADT) and a Data Structure?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures, abstract-data-type

I have found books and online resources use both terms interchangeably wihout showing much explicit distinction.

Comment: What books are you reading? Any decent introduction to data structures in language X book will make a clear distinction between these two.

Comment: Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure

Comment: From the Data Structure Wikipedia page, "The ADT defines the logical form of the data type. The data structure implements the physical form of the data type."

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I am very puzzled by the words "data structure at logical level", is this equivalent to "ADT"?

Comment: ADT is what a data type can do from user/application point of view regardless how it's implemented. Data structure is how this certain data type is implemented under the hood by the implementer (usually the company/developer that coded it)

Answer (score 36):

This may help:

> To put it simple, ADT is a logical description and data structure is concrete. ADT is the logical picture of the data and the operations to manipulate the component elements of the data. Data structure is the actual representation of the data during the implementation and the algorithms to manipulate the data elements. ADT is in the logical level and data structure is in the implementation level.

[ADT vs DS](http://abrickshort.wordpress.com/2005/03/06/abstract-data-types-vs-data-structures/)

Comment: A quick example - Linked list is an ADT and tree is one of its implementations.

Comment: @RBT I thought the tree is also a Logical level data structure... and I confusing concepts?